# Should I use SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene Name") for infinity game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have only 1 scene (It is infinity Game with one level)

Therefore, I can not find anywhere the differences and I would like to understand if there is performance or anything between those 2 codes:

```
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
```

would be the most efficient way because ints take up less memory than strings. Also, if you want to avoid the whole game pausing whilst the level is reloading, you could use

```
SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(0);
```

This will load the game asyncronously in the background so the game can carry on whilst the level is reloading.

Comment: Thank but still could you explain the difference between LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex); and     SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene Name");